# Nest each element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need my array of
`const arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f]` 
to be nested, more specifically, every element to be so.
Meaning my desired effect is for the array to looks like this `arr = [[a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f]]`

For the opposite of what I want to achieve, I could use `arr.flat()`, but that's not the case here. So I'm looking for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform something for every element of an array (in particular wrapping it inside another array). For performing an operation on every element of an array you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArr = arr.map(item => [item]);
// newArr is [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy transform process like this one:

```
const arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
const arr2 = arr.map(item => [item]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `map` over the array using a function that wraps the element in an array of 1 element:

(Note: the following snippet puts strings in the starting array just so that it runs without a ReferenceError. In practice this will work fine with any values, including variables that you have defined elsewhere in your file/script.)

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

const newArr = arr.map(el => [el]);

console.log(newArr);
```